# BASH : Extended regex grep issue

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have written below script to find a matching string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
str='XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly'
echo "str :${str}"
output=$(jvmmon -pid "$(pgrep java)" -c "print vm information" | grep -Eo "\-$str[^ ]+")
echo "output : $output"
```

Command , `jvmmon -pid "$(pgrep java)" -c "print vm information"` produce outout which contains a string named as `-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly` but I couldnt get output and it is empty.

Let say out put of that jvmmon command is `-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark`

Note : I must used grep -E as other parameters are depended on this logic.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the desired result of `grep` in this case?

Comment: @GMichael , output should be  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

Comment: What it will give you? You already know this string.

Comment: I know this string and I am trying to see jvmmon output contains that string or not and I shouldnt disturb grep -Eo pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues, both involving `+` token. `+` is an extended Regex pattern, matches one or more characters.

- In variable decalaration, you have `str='XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly'` and you are using it as Regex pattern. Then problem is it will match `:` one or more times, but you want to match it literally. So declare it as:

  ```
  str='XX:\+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly'
  ```
- In Regex pattern, you have `[^ ]+` at the end, but the input string ends at `UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly`, so is not matching. So you need `[^ ]*`.

**Example:**

```
$ str='XX:\+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly'                        
$ grep -Eo "\-${str}[^ ]*" <<<'-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly'
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```